# ATA commands to USB drive

Tags: windows, ide, scsi, ata, miniport

Windows 7
C Programming
Visual C++ 2008 (in a VMWare)

I'd like to send some ATA commands (IDENTIFY DEVICE, READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS, SET MAX ADDRESS) with `DeviceIOContro`l to a USB hard drive. Therefore I have some questions.

As I understood, USBSTOR cannot handle ATA-commands directly (with `IOCTL_ATA_PASS_THROUGH`). I tried this and it worked with the native IDE hard drive but not with USB.

1. Is it correct that applications send SCSI-commands to the device and they are forwarded to the device? So I need to create a SCSI command with the respective ATA command encapsulated?
2. With what `dwIoControlCode` can I do that? I tried it with `IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT` but the error was `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`. Could it work with minport? Is miniport still up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this link:

http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/windows-programmer-nt-kernel-mode/t-howto-send-ata-spec-command-to-usb-hdd-1646752.html

> Q: howto send ATA spec. command to USB HDD?

A: You are limited to whatever the USB->ATA tailgate (bridge) chip supports.
If you control the bridge, you can implement whatever you want. If you
don't, you'll have to ask the bridge vendor to reveal what they do support.
See my replies in the thread on 1394->ATA on NTDEV for more information.

> Q: Once more question: whether probably to get access to everyone disk
>   in SCSI RAID?

A: No.

You can only send SCSI commands to the bridge/enclosure at the end of the USB
cable. How they are translated to ATA commands - is not under your control.

I assume El Cheapo enclosures to only translate the essential SCSI commands. In
this case, you will only have 1) SCSI INQUIRY emulated by ATA IDENTIFY 2) SCSI
READ CAPACITY emulated by ATA IDENTIFY 2) READ and WRITE 3) VERIFY.

And that's all. In this case, you will have zero chances sending any
non-trivial ATA commands, since the USB-to-ATA bridge on other side provides no
ways of doing such.